# Adding multiple levels of virtual directory to application root in VS2013 MVC4 IIS express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-config, .net-4.5, iis-express, virtual-directory

I am using `Visual Studion 2013` and `MVC4`. I am using areas in application and routing rules (`RegisterArea` overrides) for each area.

My company decided to move our web application one level up in live and now I have to append `Calculator` that to all javascript scripts, css and all other paths across application + do that for all `Controllers`

What I am talking about is from

`http://host:1234/legal-services/Wills/Index`

to `http://host:1234/legal-services/Calculator/Wills/Index`

so after replacing all the scripts I went to `csproj` and added override for application root so it would do override to all controllers, but this was completely ignored.

[image]

I am assuming when overriding host one only can work with hostname and port but not folders.

**UPDATE:**
I have also tried directly modifying `.csproj` file to change `IISUrl` setting

from
`<IISUrl>http://localhost:50766/legal-services/</IISUrl>`
to
`<IISUrl>http://localhost:50766/legal-services/Calculator/</IISUrl>`

but this had no effect ether.

**UPDATE2:**

So change was in configuration in `applicationHost.config` in `C:\Users\[username]\Documents\IISExpress\config`, to add additional virtual directory

From

```
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\hg\Website" /> 
    <virtualDirectory path="/legal-services" physicalPath="C:\hg\Website" />
```

to

```
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\hg\Website" /> 
    <virtualDirectory path="/legal-services/calculator" physicalPath="C:\hg\Website" />
```

however now I am running into different issue since I am now dealing with multiple layers on virtual directories I got 403 and it makes perfect sense since path in the middle (`/legal-services`) is not within the list.

When I added

```
 <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\hg\Website" /> 
<virtualDirectory path="/legal-services/calculator" physicalPath="C:\hg\Website" />
<virtualDirectory path="/legal-services" physicalPath="C:\hg\Website" />
```

I got configuration error (I am assuming because all 3 paths are pointing to same directory)

`It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`

`<authentication mode="Forms">`

Which indicates that path is not identified as web application or there is web.config conflict.

**How could configure this so that path="/legal-services/calculator" would be identified as application without web.config conflicts ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to create two separate application paths in `applicationHost.config` like following where main path has part of virtual directory path and second application has full virtual directory path like following:

```
<site name="Website-Site" id="2">
     <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\hg\Website" />
        <virtualDirectory path="/legal-services" physicalPath="C:\hg\" />
    </application> 
    <application path="/legal-services/Calculator" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\hg\Website" />
    </application>              
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50766:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: Jexus Manager might be an easier solution for such managmenet, http://jexusmanager.com